# Nested list to pandas DataFrame with fixed number of columns

Tags: python, list, dataframe

New to Python. Would like to convert below list to pandas dataframe with fixed number of columns

[['Teja'], ['22', 'Male'], ['Viha'], ['Female'], ['Male'], ['Vinay'], ['32', 'Female'], ['Sowmya']]

[DataFrame-Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tekt8.png)

Comment: IS your list organized as [[name],[age,gender]]  or as your example?

Comment: No. it is not organized as [[name],[age,gender]]. It is just a random list

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your code attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking at.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [
    ["Teja"],
    ["22", "Male"],
    ["Viha"],
    ["Female"],
    ["Male"],
    ["Vinay"],
    ["32", "Female"],
    ["Sowmya"],
]

name = []
age = []
gender = []
for item in a:
    if "Male" in item or "Female" in item:
        if item[0].isnumeric():
            age.append(item[0])
            gender.append(item[1])
        else:
            age.append("None")
            gender.append(item[0])
        continue
    name.append(item[0])

data = {"name": name, "age": age, "gender": gender}

print(name, age, gender)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary like this:

```
d = {
    'name'  : ['Teja', 'Viha', 'Vinay', 'Sowmya'],
    'age'   : [22, None, None, 32],
    'gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']
}
my_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(d)
print(my_dataframe)
```

The output would be like:

```
     name   age  gender
0    Teja  22.0    Male
1    Viha   NaN  Female
2   Vinay   NaN    Male
3  Sowmya  32.0  Female
```

Comment: The question was how to convert existing data, not how to type it and make dataframe